# Upgrading Drupal 8 to a newer version from the command line using Drush?

Tags: 8, drush, upgrading

Currently I have stable Drupal 8.1 release and I would like to uprgrade my site to 8.2 dev. How can I do this via the command line with Drush if that is even possible?

- If not using drush, can I just download 8.2 and extract it into 8.1 directory?

Comment: I believe one method is replacing the core directory and running composer update, to get any package updates / new composer additions. Could be wrong on that last part.

Answer (score 1):

To do it via the command line you can simply run the command `drush up drupal`

To do it manually, it's a bit more tedious as you need to be really careful about what you want to keep, templates.. modules... themes. Basically you need to replace all core files at the root level and note that the files that reside at the root level e.g. .htaccess.. robots.txt need to be compared and merged with the latest.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Note that `drush up drupal` will not take you from Drupal 8.1.8 to any Drupal 8.2.x release, because Drupal 8.2.x has no stable releases yet. Specify the version number per my answer to switch from a stable to a newer dev or beta release.

Comment: From Drupal 8.1.x to 8.2.0-rc1 you can do `drush up drupal-8.2.0-rc1`

Answer (score 1):

Try `drush pm-update drupal-8.2.0-beta2` for the beta2 release, or `drush pm-update drupal-8.2.x` for the dev release.